# Faker.Credit_card_number function to generate cards from specific providers

Tags: python, pandas, faker

I am using the below function to generate some random Credit card numbers of Amex/Mastercard/Visa & Discover and writing it to a csv file based on a record_counter.

If my record_counter is set to 25, I see some of the records comes out as 0 and rest with Credit card numbers. Is there a way to generate a credit card number always despite the record counter value. ( If record_counter is 100, there needs to be 100 credit card numbers generated ) I know this may not be the optimized way of implementation, but I am just beginning on Python,

```
def PanGeneratorFaker():
fake = Faker()

k = fake.credit_card_number()
if (str(k).startswith("34") or str(k).startswith("37")) and (len(k) == 15):
    return k
elif (str(k).startswith("6") or str(k).startswith("4") or str(k).startswith("5")) and ((len(k) == 16) or (len(k) == 19)):
    return k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
fake.credit_card_number(card_type='amex')
```

where card_type could be maestro, mastercard, visa16, visa13, visa19, amex, discover, diners, jcb15, jcb16.

If you need more details take a look on [source code](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/credit_card/__init__.py).

Comment: That helps! It takes more time when fake.credit_card_number is used to create even just 10000 records. I might as well use random module to generate 16 digit numbers, which is quick. ( I am not looking for cards that has right check digit number but just some random numbers )